# Best way of marking this up in BEM CSS

Tags: css, module, sass, methodology, bem

I have been starting to use BEM as a CSS methodology for organizing my CSS and over the course of the projects, pretty much everything has turned into a module.

I put layout styles for a module in the parent module. That has been working nicely.

What has been confusing me and I can't grasp a hold of is something like this: Say I have the following:

```
<div class="picture-holder">
  <div class="picture-box">
    <img class="image" />
    <span class="caption">text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="picture-box">
    <img class="image" />
    <span class="caption">text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So at this stage, following the rules of BEM, I would add the parent class name of a module to it's own module name:

```
<div class="picture-holder">
  <div class="picture-holder__picture-box">
    <img class="image" />
    <span class="caption">text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="picture-holder__picture-box">
    <img class="picture-box__image" />
    <span class="picture-box__caption">text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then add the sole module name to each one:

```
<div class="picture-holder">
  <div class="picture-holder__picture-box picture-box">
    <img class="image" />
    <span class="caption">text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="picture-holder__picture-box picture-box">
    <img class="picture-box__image image" />
    <span class="picture-box__caption caption">text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does this look right?

What would you call the individual files holding each of the module styles?:
- picture-box.sass
- picture-holder.sass
- picture.sass
- caption.sass

It seems like whenever I get nesting like this, I end up with a module that hardly has a meaning or is something too generic like "picture", "image", "box" or "caption"

I get the same problems higher up the hierarchy. So where I have a wrapping `div` around the site, e.g.: `.container`, I now have `.container-header`, `.container-main` and `.container-footer`.

I like the main concept behind BEM and everything in modules but it's the module in module thing I get confused with.

All the articles explaining BEM, never talk about this and show super simple examples that don't hit this issue.

Am I doing it wrong?

I basically just want peoples ideas on this subject and how I can improve?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121289/are-questions-about-naming-classes-relevant-on-stack-exchange and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-about-naming-conventions

Comment: May I ask how you use the `.picture-holder`-module? Is the container necessary everywhere? Are there only two pictures in it or more?

Comment: picture-holder is normally what contains picture boxes, as many as needed and a picture-box has the image plus a caption. This setup is what I normally use on a standard content page alongside text and is either floated left or right

Answer (score 2):

you are on the right track, but you don't need to add the 'base' class without the module prefix.

Here is your version:

```
<div class="picture-holder">
  <div class="picture-holder__picture-box picture-box">
    <img class="image" />
    <span class="caption">text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="picture-holder__picture-box picture-box">
    <img class="picture-box__image image" />
    <span class="picture-box__caption caption">text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what you likely need:

```
<div class="picture-holder">
  <div class="picture-box">
    <img class="picture-box__image" />
    <span class="picture-box__caption">text</span>
  </div> 
  <div class="picture-box">
    <img class="picture-box__image" />
    <span class="picture-box__caption">text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Depending on how you are going to use 'picture-box' you could further simplify:

```
<div class="picture-holder">
  <div class="picture-holder__box">
    <img class="picture-holder__image" />
    <span class="picture-holder__caption">text</span>
  </div> 
  <div class="picture-holder__box">
    <img class="picture-holder__image" />
    <span class="picture-holder__caption">text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks for that. How would you deal with the top level, container, container-header, container-footer, container-main and sub elements of those? So taking the nesting a level further?

Comment: There are a number of possibilities, it's up to you. The thing you want to keep in mind is to modularize, so that you could put any module any place on the page and have it work correctly. Not everything in your html/css needs to be BEM syntax, mainly just portable modules.